# javascript get all divs by child text?

Tags: javascript

I have html format like below. I am trying to get Div where attribute foo = 'bar' which I can get but only if that div has a child with certain text.

```
   var loop = document.querySelectorAll('[foo="bar"]');
        for(var i = 0; i <= loop.length; i++)  
       //perform action

<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> barfoo </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example html above I would like to fetch the first and third div where foo=bar and ignore the second as it des not have a child span with text of foobar.

My javascript above will fetch all 3 but then in my loop how do I check if the child span text matches foobar before executing action?

Thanks

Comment: It can be done, but it would result in horrible performance.

Comment: There is no build selector that does this right now, they were thinking about a `:contains` selector, but it does not exist (yet?). [Selectors Level 3: 6.6.6. Blank](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#content-selectors). So you need to do the filtering on the found elements yourself using e.g. [MDN: Node.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var loop = document.querySelectorAll('[foo="bar"]');
loop.forEach((element, index)=>{
  if(element.innerText.match(/foobar/)){
    //Do something with element
  }
})
```

```html
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> barfoo </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `innerHTML` if it is about the text, because this would also take attributes and tags into account.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is using XPath:

```js
// Replace document.body with the common ancestor
const xpResult = document.evaluate("div[@foo='bar'][descendant::text()[contains(., 'foobar')]]", document.body);

const elems = [];
{
  let elem = xpResult.iterateNext();
  while (elem) {
    elems.push(elem);
    elem = xpResult.iterateNext();
  }
}
console.log(elems);

for (const elem of elems) {
  elem.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> barfoo </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The translation of `div[@foo='bar'][descendant::text()[contains(., 'foobar')]]` to English is: All `<div>` elements (children of `document.body`) which contain a `foo` attribute with the value `"bar"` and which contain descendant text nodes which contain `"foobar"` in their text.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know, you tagged your question with "javascript" (so, maybe plain javascript) but what about a query with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[foo=bar]").find( ":contains('foobar')").css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> barfoo </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div foo='bar'>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span> foobar </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works with really old versions of jQuery.